# ItemAdded event not firing after document conversion in drop off library

Tags: event-receivers, document-converter, records-center

I'm trying to build events for a drop off library in a records centre in order to convert Word docs to PDF using the Word automation service.

The conversion event files on ItemCheckedIn, and works fine.

This produces a .pdf file with none of the  associated meta data of the original .doc file in teh same library.

I have build a second event reciever to run on ItemAdded, and this is intended to copy the meta data from the original file if a .pdf file is added and this is a converted file.

UNFORTUNATELY the ItemAdded event runs when the .doc is first uploaded, **but NOT when the .pdf file is added to the list from the Word Automation Service.**

I've tried the ItemUpdate and the ItemConverted events with no luck.

There is nothing in ULS I can see, I get the following info message to say the conversion worked:

```
Local Controller 'be616404-d025-4d78-88d8-2b7a3bb8016f': Success: <http://dev-rhsp/ia/CErcf/DropOffLibrary/test.doc> uploaded to <http://dev-rhsp/ia/CErcf/DropOffLibrary/test.pdf>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a workflow to do that, event receivers will not be executed with word automation services.

Here you have a full tutorial in how to do it.
http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2010/04/19/word-automation-services-solution-sample-workflow.aspx

Comment: Hi, We are trying to get events / workflows to work in this scenario, but neither fire...? We are busy trying a timer job now.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, making a VS workflow to do all the work.

Answer (score 0):

We are on Sharepoint 2010 and the Word Automation Service definitely DOES fire ItemAdding and ItemAdded at least when we converted docx, docm files to PDF. I suggest adding some logging or tracing code.

Also, we found that we had to recycle the services application pool otherwise the Word Automation Service holds on to the old version of the event receiver.

Also, in a multi server environment, there could potentially be multiple instances of Word Automation Services, I suggest disabling them on all but one server while troubleshooting.